# OnChange event handlers don't get called when I'm updating a form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a form that should update my applications state as a user types in the input field and in the textarea. The input and textarea call their event handlers through onChange={event handler}. For some reason when I type in either field the event handlers don't get called at all. The input and textarea fields seem to work fine outside of a form though.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import LogoutHeader from './LogoutHeader';
import { fetchTodo, updateTodo, deleteTodo } from '../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

    class ShowTodo extends Component {

        static contextTypes = {
            router: PropTypes.object
        };

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                descriptionChanged: false,
                newDescription: '',
                newTitle: '',
                done: false,
                id: 0
            };


            this.handleDescriptionChange = this.handleDescriptionChange.bind(this);
            this.handleDeleteClick = this.handleDeleteClick.bind(this);
            this.changeButtons = this.changeButtons.bind(this);
            this.handleSaveClick = this.handleSaveClick.bind(this);
            this.handleUndoClick = this.handleUndoClick.bind(this);
            this.handleTitleChange = this.handleTitleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleDoneChange = this.handleDoneChange.bind(this);
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            this.props.fetchTodo(this.props.params.id).then(() => {

                this.setState({
                    newDescription: this.props.todo.description,
                    newTitle: this.props.todo.title,
                    done: this.props.todo.completed,
                    id: this.props.todo.id
                }); 

            });
        }

        render() {

            const { todo } = this.props;
            const { fields: {title, description}, handleSubmit } = this.props;

            console.log("Fields: description: ", this.props.fields.description.value); //These values change as expected
            console.log("Fields: title: ", this.props.fields.title.value);


            if (!todo) {
                return (
                    <h3>Loading...</h3>
                );
            }

            return (
                <div id="showTodo">

                <Link id="btnBack" className="btn btn-custom" role="button" to="/todos_index"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></Link>

                    <LogoutHeader></LogoutHeader>

                        <div className="row">

                            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSaveClick)}>
                                        <h3>Edit Todo</h3>
                                        <div className={`form-group ${title.touched && title.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                                            <label>Title</label>
                                            <input 
                                                type="text" 
                                                className="form-control"
                                                value={this.state.newTitle}
                                                onChange={this.handleTitleChange}
                                                {...title} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="text-help">
                                            {description.touched ? description.error : ''}
                                        </div>
                                        <div className={`form-group ${description.touched && description.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                                            <label>Description</label>
                                            <textarea
                                                className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.newDescription}
                                                onChange={this.handleDescriptionChange}
                                                {...description} >
                                            </textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="text-help">
                                            {description.touched ? description.error : ''}
                                        </div>
                                        <span className="input-group-btn">
                                            {this.changeButtons()}
                                            <button id="editTodoDelete" className="btn btn-custom" onClick={this.handleDeleteClick}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                                        </span>
                                    </form>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                </div>
            );
        }

        changeButtons() { //This does not get called when there are changed in the input or textareas.

            if (!this.state.descriptionChanged) {
                return null;
            } else {

                return [
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  id="editTodoSave"
                  className="btn btn-custom"
                  ><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>,
                <button
                  id="editTodoRefresh"
                  className="btn btn-custom"
                  onClick={this.handleUndoClick}
                  ><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
               ];
            }
        }

        handleDescriptionChange(event) { //This does not get called when there is a change in the textarea
            this.setState({
                descriptionChanged: true,
                newDescription: this.props.fields.description.value
            });

        }

        handleTitleChange(event) { //This does not get called when there is a changed in the input field.

            this.setState({
                descriptionChanged: true,
                newTitle: this.props.fields.title.value
            });

        }

        handleDoneChange() {

            this.setState({
                done: !this.state.done
            });

            var props = {
                completed: this.state.done
            };

            this.props.updateTodo(this.state.id, JSON.stringify(props));

        }

        handleDeleteClick() {
            this.props.deleteTodo(this.state.id).then(() => {
                this.context.router.push('/todos_index');
            });
        }

        handleSaveClick(props) {

            this.props.updateTodo(this.state.id, JSON.stringify(props)).then(() => {
                alert("Todo updates should have been recieved in database");
                this.context.router.push('/todos_index');
            }); 

        }

        handleUndoClick() {

            this.setState({
                descriptionChanged: false,
                newTitle: this.props.todo.title,
                newDescription: this.props.todo.description,
                errors: {
                    title: '',
                    description: ''
                }

            });
        }
    }

    function validate(values) {
        const errors = {};

        if (!values.title) {
            errors.title = 'Please enter a title';
        }

        if (values.title) {
            if (values.title.length > 25){
                errors.title = 'You exceeded 25 characters';
            }

        }

        if (!values.description) {
            errors.description = 'Please enter your description';
        }

        if (values.description) {
            if (values.description.length > 500) {
                errors.description = "You exceeded 500 characters";
            }
        }

        return errors;
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return { todo: state.todos.todo };
    }

    export default reduxForm({
        form: 'ShowTodoForm',
        fields: ['title', 'description'],
        validate                                   //These configurations will be added to the application state, so reduxForm is very similar to the connect function.
                                                   //connect: first argument is mapStateToProps, second is mapDispatchToProps
                                                   //reduxForm: 1st is form configuration, 2nd is mapStateToProps, 3rd is mapDispatchToProps

    }, mapStateToProps, { fetchTodo, updateTodo, deleteTodo })(ShowTodo);
```

Comment: can you post your all component?
and why `onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSaveClick)}` may you should change it too `onSubmit={this.handleSaveClick}`

Comment: handleSubmit is a function from redux-form that organizes the values pulled from each field in your form. Notice I don't pass handleSaveClick any parameters because redux-form's handleSubmit automatically handles that.

Comment: r u sure the function don't trigger at all?
i think your issue in update the state

Comment: Could you be more specific? When I console.log the state, it doesn't change. That means the state is either not updating or the event handlers aren't being triggered at all. The only thing that changes is this.props.fields.description.value which should be set to state. They should change hand in hand.

Comment: i mean did you try to add console.log inside `handleTitleChange` function?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if the issue solved or not

Comment: I am also experiencing this with Redux Form, the onChange callbacks aren't getting called at all. Have you had any luck in the last couple of weeks?

Comment: ntdb, it's the weirdest thing isn't it? In different components within the same project, I use redux-form and the onChange callbacks work perfectly fine, but in this particular component they won't work at all. What I ended up doing was ditching redux form completely just for that component and using regular callback functions on an input and a textarea. Besides this one component in question, redux form has worked well.